# Appropriate place to dispatch action for fetching server data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I'm new to React and I'm trying to figure out the best way to request information from the server based on the URL. I'm using Redux and React Router v4.

Let's say I have a route `/foo/:id`, and a component `Foo` that will render something based on `id`. However `Foo` needs some server data related to `id` to do so. I believe the way to accomplish this would be to use `mapDispatchToProps` to create a function that takes `id` as input, does some async work, dispatches an action, and ultimately updates the redux state.

My question is: where is the most appropriate place to invoke the dispatch? In this scenario, there's no form submission or button click to kick things off. Originally I was thinking of including a check for the `id` data in `render()` and fetching if it was not populated, but this felt wrong due to the side effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in `componentDidMount` of the `Foo` component, similar to [this example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/real-world/src/containers/RepoPage.js#L30-L32) from the Redux GitHub project.

Your intuition is right that `render` is not a good place to do so. Most people do it in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method of the component.

On a relevant note, you will also want to do fetching also in the `componentWillReceiveProps` method like [what they did here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/real-world/src/containers/RepoPage.js#L34-L38). Reason being if your user navigated from `foo/1/` to `foo/2/`, the component is already on the screen and will not be mounted again, hence `componentDidMount` will not be called again. The fetching for the second user will be done in the `componentWillReceiveProps` method.

Answer (score 1):

i think the best way to do the dispatch inside the componentWillReceiveProps() which would help you fetch some data before the component renders

Answer (score 1):

It seems your use case is well-captured by the `react-refetch` package which you can find [here](https://github.com/heroku/react-refetch). It provides a higher-order component that allows you to specify dependencies at specific API endpoints and then resolves them when a new instance of your component is created.

Importantly it injects the data into your components `props` using a synchronous abstraction of a promise called a `PromiseState`. This will allow you to conditionally render your component depending on whether the data is say `pending`, `fulfilled`, `rejected`, etc.

This is not attached in any way to Redux, it skips that layer entirely, so do keep it in mind that the response is directly injected into the component and does not go through your redux store's state.